# Using generic return value in static method Java

Tags: java, generics

here is my code

```
class MyClass<E> {

   public static List<E> myUtilMethod(){

   }
}
```

Once I compile this, I get this error

> non-static type variable E cannot be referenced from a static context

How I can return a generic type from this method?

Comment: you're trying to put a return type on a class? try <T> instead

Comment: nevermind I figured it out, thanks
no I am not. I changed my method signature to 
public static <E> List<E> and it worked

Comment: That `<E>` is not the same as the `<E>` as defined in `MyClass`, though.  You're going to want to rename that generic.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Your MyClass instances vary by some type parameter E, so you can have e.g. one MyClass<String> instance and one MyClass<Integer>. But the static myUtilMethod(), how can you decide if it is to return List<String> or List<Integer>? If it were public static <T> List<T> myUtilMethod(T arg) you'd know the type from the argument passed into the method, but in your example there are no args.

Comment: *Never* use the `static` key word *unless you have a good reason*! (and no: *"It's a *utility method* in a *utility class."* does  **not** qualify as a good reason...)

Answer (score 7):

You need to add the type parameter to your `myUtilMethod` method...

```
public static <T> List<T> myUtilMethod() {
               ^
               |------- here!!

    // TODDY
    return someList;
}
```

edit:

as  [makoto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto) spotted,  is in that case not the same as the  defined in `MyClass`, though. you should rename that generic type to something else... (T in the code I posted!)

Comment: As @Makoto mentioned in his comment on the question, you have to be aware, that `T` can be a different type than the class type parameter `E`